# How to import file from parent folder?

Tags: ruby

This is my folder struct:

```
/home/user/ruby/forecast
├── forecast/
│   ├── api
│   ├── olimp/
│   │   ├── api.rb
│   │   ├── live/
│   │   │   ├── collect.rb
│   │   │   └── convert.rb
│   │   └── blog.rb
│   │
```

I need to import in file `collect.rb` code from `api.rb`
I trying to make it so: `require_relative '../api'` , and have the following error:

```
/home/user/ruby/forecast/olimp/live/convert.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/user/ruby/forecast/olimp/live/api (LoadError)
    from /home/user/ruby/forecast/olimp/live/convert.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/ruby/forecast/olimp/live/collect.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /home/user/ruby/forecast/olimp/live/collect.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How about `require_relative './../api'`

Comment: @Gerhard same: `/home/sonyboy/ruby/forecast/olimpbet/live/convert.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/sonyboy/ruby/forecast/olimpbet/live/api (LoadError)`

Comment: I cannot recreate this issue [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/OverdueMoccasinUser#main.rb)

Comment: @engineersmnky Then I dont unterstand why do I have this error

Comment: Double check your code, maybe it's a typo? What you are showing would be the result of `require_relative './api'`